# Relation between payment made with createbutton api and ipn message

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-buttons

Our customers sends their requests for our products via email. Their requests are saved in our database and after we check their requests, we want to send them an email which contains the paypal payment link. To execute this, I am using **BMCreateButton** method of **ButtonManager** API of Paypal.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/

This method returns **EMAILLINK** parameter and I am using this parameter in the email to redirect to user to paypal payment page. This method also returns **HOSTEDBUTTONID** and I am saving this parameter and **EMAILLINK** parameter to the database to make a relation between the email link(**hostedbuttonid**) and the user request.

For the payment notifications, I think my only choice is IPN of Paypal. I developed a page to handle the IPN messages from paypal and it works fine but the problem arises when I want to relate between the payment information with the email link that was sent to the customer. I mean I want to know for which request this payment was made. IPN message does not return any information about the **HOSTEDBUTTONID**. It returns **btn_id**(different than the **HOSTEDBUTTONID**), **txn_id** and **ipn_track_id**  but none of them is useful to relate the customer request( or email sent) with the payment.

Do you have any suggestion about my issue? Or do you think I should use another way for sending the payment email to the user instead of **BMCreateButton** method of **ButtonManager** API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BMCreateButton call, where you're setting up the standard PayPal variables for the button, add the CUSTOM parameter.  Within that you can pass any value you want (up to 256 char.) and then that same value will come back in the IPN so you can relate it accordingly.

If you have a specific Order ID you could use the INVOICE field instead, and that would come back in IPN as well.

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I also found this custom parameter solution yesterday. Thanks again.